# Erro acessando ponteiro

Tags: c++, ponteiro

```
int main()
{
    int**items[5];
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        *items[i] = new int; <--
    }
    return 0;
}
```

O programa compila, mas não roda. Rodei o *debugger* e apontou que o erro está onde a seta aponta.

Meu objetivo é que o meu ponteiro de um vetor aponte para outra memória dinâmica para armazenar apenas um `int`.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: tire um asterisco da declaração de items. o que voce esta fazendo e alocando um vetor de 5 posições com ponteiros para outros vetores. logo uma matriz de 3 dimensões.

Comment: Qual é  erro que o depurador indica?

Answer (score 1):

Com esta declaração

```
int** items[5];
```

na realidade, estás a declarar um array de 5 elementos os quais são ponteiros a ponteiros. Sinceramente não percebo porque precisas duma coisa assim tão complicada.

O que acho que tu precisas é simplesmente um array de ponteiros

```
int* items[5]; // array de 5 ponteiros
```

ou o ponteiro a outros ponteiros.

```
int** items;
```

Pensa um bocado no que está a fazer nesta instrução:

```
*items[i] = new int;
```

O que é `items[i]`? 
Ponteiro.

O que acontece se desreferencias um ponteiro? 
Acedes a memoria pontada, mas to teu caso não existe nenhuma memória alocada. Para alocar memória para o ponteiro de segundo nível tens que primeiro alocar memória para aqueles de primeiro. 
O que tens que fazer primeiro é alocar memória para os ponteiros do array e só depois para os ponteiros que os ponteiros do array pontão.

```
int** array[2];
array[0] = new int*; // alocar memoria para um ponteiro que ponta a um ponteiro
*array[0] = new int; // agora podes alocar memoria para o ponteiro de segundo nivel.
```

Answer (score 0):

Não vejo sentido em você declarar uma variável como ponteiro e fixar o tamaho do vetor estaticamente (ou seja, na própria declaração da variável).

Ao invés de fazer isso:

```
  int ** items[5];
```

Você deve fazer isso:

```
  int ** items = new int*[5];
```

e ao invés de fazer isso:

```
 *items[i] = new int;
```

Você deve fazer isso:

```
 items[i] = new int;
```